# How to SET the local variable value equal to result from CTE table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsqlt

I have a question
We have a table HR like this

```
EmpName    Empmanager
Jack        Jane
Tom         Jane 
Tony        Victor
Isabella    Hugo
Anna        Victor
```

So I want to extract the DISTINCT emp.manager then select them by line and give them to a variable suppose mgrname. I got error at SET @mgrname syntax?

```
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @mgrname VARCHAR(20)
SET @count = 3
WITH  MGRlist as(
    SELECT DISTINCT Empmanager FROM HR)
    **SET @mgrname** = SELECT Empmanager  FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mgr ASC) AS RowNumber,
    *
    FROM MGRlist
    ) AS RESULT
    WHERE RowNumber = @count -- FIND THE CURRENT MANAGER NAME
```

Comment: you need to call cte right after that as it cannot be referred after another transaction which is your set, I think temp table would be better idea than cte in this case

Comment: Can you help me write an example I'm new to SQL

Comment: Please see my example below

Comment: @TonyAnderson You cannot use SET within CTE, refer my answer below. I think it would probably solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the distinct manager name in that case you don't need `CTE`.

You are trying to insert multiple values in a `VARCHAR` data type

```
DECLARE @mgrname VARCHAR(20)
```

Instead of creating a `VARCHAR` variable, you should be creating a `TABLE` type variable which can hold multiple values like following.

```
DECLARE @mgrname TABLE(ManagerName VARCHAR(100))
```

To fetch specific count of distinct manager names you can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@count)
```

Your final query should look like following.

```
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @mgrname table (ManagerName VARCHAR(100))
SET @count = 3

INSERT INTO @mgrname
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@count)  Empmanager FROM HR
ORDER BY Empmanager
--Now output is stored inside a table variable.
SELECT * FROM @mgrname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'Jack'      as Empname ,  'Jane'   as empmanager
into #temp1  union all 
select 'Tom'       as Empname ,  'Jane'   as empmanager union all  
select 'Tony'      as Empname ,  'Victor' as empmanager union all 
select 'Isabella'  as Empname ,  'Hugo'   as empmanager union all 
select 'Anna'      as Empname ,  'Victor' as empmanager  


DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @mgrname VARCHAR(20)
SET @count = 3

SELECT DISTINCT Empmanager into #temp2 FROM #temp1


set @mgrname =   (SELECT Empmanager  FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY empmanager ASC) AS RowNumber,
*
FROM #temp2
) AS RESULT
WHERE RowNumber = @count)  -- FIND THE CURRENT MANAGER NAME

select @mgrname as CurrentManagername
```

Output:

```
   CurrentManagername
    Victor
```

You can create a temp table instead and use that to refer until the session is active.

Comment: DROP TABLE MGRLIST CREATE TABLE MGRLIST(mgr INT) WITH TEMP as( SELECT DISTINCT mgr FROM emp) INSERT INTO MGRLIST// Can we somehow do it this way, cause if the table get bigger and manager list is bigger then do it manually line by line is not very efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @mgrname VARCHAR(20)
SET @count = 3
;WITH  MGRlist as(
    SELECT DISTINCT Empmanager FROM HR)
    SELECT @mgrname= Empmanager  FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Empmanager ASC) AS RowNumber,
    *
    FROM MGRlist
    ) AS RESULT
    WHERE RowNumber = @count
```